# Running with values from selected web.%.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform

In .NET Core if running with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Devlopment` the values in `appsettings.json` will be overwriten by `appsettings.Development.json` values if they are set, and the `Development` file is read.

But that doesn't seem to be the case with `web.config`

[image]

Is there a way to achieve it so that when I'm running on `Debug` build, the `AppKey` setting will be taken from `Web.Debug.config` file and not `Web.config`? I looked into web.config transforms, but from what I understood it only happens when doing a publish

Comment: I think Launch Profiles could help you. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: on .net core it would, but this is .net framework